# Why do cron commands inside a docker container show up in log but don't actually run?

Tags: docker, cron, redhat

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM almalinux:8

# [... supervisord setup ...]

RUN dnf install -y \
    crontabs
RUN sed -ri '/-session(\s+)optional(\s+)pam_systemd.so/d' /etc/pam.d/system-auth && \
    sed -ri '/^[^#]/ s/systemd//g' /etc/nsswitch.conf
COPY $TEMPLATE_DIR/supervisord/crond.conf /etc/supervisord.d/crond.conf
```

`crond.conf`

```
[program:crond]
    command=/usr/sbin/crond -nsm off
    stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
    stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
    stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
    stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

syslog:

```
2022-06-13 18:39:07,939 INFO success: crond entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

`crontab -e`

```
*       *       *       *       *       touch /var/www/html/test.txt
```

syslog:

```
Jun 13 18:57:59 e60d29fd100e crontab[331]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jun 13 18:58:15 e60d29fd100e crontab[331]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Jun 13 18:58:15 e60d29fd100e crontab[331]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Jun 13 18:59:01 e60d29fd100e CROND[334]: (root) CMD (touch /var/www/html/test.txt)
```

I thought the file is never touched... tried also `echo`, running an absolute path command... nothing. But after waiting a little (longer) and running cron with debug flags on, it seems the command does get run, but with something like a 5s to 50s delay:

```
load_entry()...about to parse command
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352923611Z linenum=21
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352929349Z load_entry()...returning successfully
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352934854Z ...load_user() done
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352940748Z unlinking old database:
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352960040Z check_inotify_database is done
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352966537Z user [root:0:0:...] cmd="touch /var/www/html/test.txt"
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352972511Z [10] do_command(touch /var/www/html/test.txt, (root,0,0))
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352979069Z [10] main process returning to work
2022-06-13T16:17:01.352984792Z
```

The huge delay seems to also pile up what I presume are queued commands to run, and the pile grows forever larger:

```
root         335  0.0  0.0  69708  5188 ?        S    19:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/CROND -nsm off -x ext,sch,proc,pars,load,misc
root         336 94.4  0.0  69708  1440 ?        Rs   19:15   8:52 /usr/sbin/CROND -nsm off -x ext,sch,proc,pars,load,misc

... multiply 10x the 2 processes above after a few minutes ...
```

Any clues why the huge delay and weird behavior? Disabling inotify (`-i`) on crond does not improve things... I'm thinking maybe a time skew issue?

Comment: You don't have an ENTRYPOINT or a CMD in your Dockerfile, so the default command should be /bin/bash from the almalinux base image. Are you doing anything to start the cron daemon?

Comment: Hi @HansKilian, yes, it's all in `# [... supervisord setup ...]` (too long to include here). But it does start and run as you can see from the syslog output. Also updated the question details, it seems the cron does run, but hugely delayed.